# Python Version of Perl = || (= Or)

Tags: python

I can't seem to find a python way of saying

```
x = y or 1
```

In Perl:

```
$x = $y || 1;
```

Is there a nice way to do this in python?

Comment: What's not working with `x = y or 1`?

Comment: My program was failing and it looked like that was the issue but it wasn't. x = y or 1 is correct. Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python's `or` has what I believe are the semantics you're looking for. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#or). It's important to realize that it returns the input value(s), not `True` or `False`.

```
>>> "" or 12
12

>>> 27 or 9
27

>> None or "default"
'default'
```

This should mean that `x = y or 1` should be what you're after, `x` will be `y` if `y` is non-`False`, else it will be `1`.

Answer (score 4):

`x = y or 1` is the same as:

```
if y:
  x = y
else:
  x = 1
```

Isn't it what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

```
y = 2
x = y if y else 1
# x == 2

y = None
x = y if y else 1
# x == 1
```

Answer (score 2):

All the solutions mentioned will work if y is defined (it can be None)

If y is not defined Python will throw an exception, while the Perl code will work in non-strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

A simple one but not that nice:

```
x = y if y else 1
```